# Is it possible to run automated workflows in Sharepoint Foundation 2010 by the System Account?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, timer-jobs

I have installed SharePoint Foundation server 2010 (Standalone) on a windows 7 machine for learning SharePoint development. I have created a workflow, but it is not getting started automatically when the item in the list is created/edited.

I searched on the Goggle and found that Workflows do not run automatically with system account login. The Workflow works fine when started manually.

I want to know if there are any workarounds for this situation. Is there any setting that can be turned On/Off to allow this to work.

Thanks for your time. Please comment if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should login with different account other than System Account. **System Account** is not allowed to run workflows for security purposes.

Read more about why it is blocked. http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/03/14/workflows-do-not-start.aspx

Comment: Does this mean that I have to create a separate administrative account on my machine, set it as the site owner and then publish and run the workflow from that user?

Comment: Yee.that is right way